# Why is a regex pattern not giving me the correct output in the url redirect?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am in the middle of migrating a site that has some urls that are in need to 301 redirects.

We have been looking at the site and trying to fathom the best route to getting the urls that are currently there and making them work with the new site.

The issues we face are the fact that a lot of the urls are 3 segments deep on the old site and the new one has only 1 segment and we need to match slugs and make sure we can identify a slug in the old url and match it against the new one. Here is the url structure:

**Old site**

/our-products/accessories/valerie-objects-alfred-collection-lucy-rug

/shop-name/newest-additions-shop-online-shop/valerie-objects-alfred-collection-lucy-rug

/shop-name/contemporary-design-accessories-gifts/valerie-objects-alfred-collection-lucy-rug

**New site**

/valerie-objects-lucy-rug

Heres  my attempt at a regex pattern that is not working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/our-products\/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ /([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1
```

What is being output on the url https://sitename/our-products/sofas/about-a-lounge-sofa with this is below:

```
/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/sofas
```

In the above we would need to be able to pick up the old urls and strip the segments out leaving the title slug and a way to match that with the product on the site already.

Is this possible and what would we be looking at for a regex pattern?

Comment: In Old site above you will see these are examples of the old urls and what they all need to be because they are from the same product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirect rule should work for you:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:our-products|shop-name)/.+/(\w+-\w+-)(?:.*-)?(\w+-\w+)$ /$1$2
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: anubhava that works perfectly in terms of redirect. Is there a way we can match so it redirects to a url that exists. So for instance `/shop-name/newest-additions-shop-online-shop/valerie-objects-alfred-collection-lucy-rug` will be on the new site `/valerie-objects-lucy-rug`

Comment: Brilliant thanks anubhava. Can this regex also be used to check for matching slugs in a single url like `/test-product-with-unique-url` redirecting to `/unique-url`?

Comment: Yes exactly! can the above regex be applied to this to it just looks for a matching string in that url?

Comment: Okay so nothing out of the regex above can be applied?

Comment: Oh sorry: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]*-(\w+-\w+)$ /$1`

Comment: What does the above actually do @anubhava?

Comment: Sorry just being interested/enquisitive

Comment: You may join chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171482/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-anubhava and I can answer any doubts/clarifications.

Comment: Cannot load chat in chrome or Firefox